# How to convert curl request to requests module in python

Tags: python, curl, request, urllib

How to convert this curl request to python requests module compitable(Post request)

```
curl 'http://sss.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36' -H --data 'aq=%40syssource%3DProFind%20AND%20NOT%20%40title%3DCoveo%20AND%20NOT%20%40title%3Derror&searchHub=ProFind&xxx=yyy&xxx=yyy&xxx=yyy=10&xxx=yyy' --compressed
```

I am searching for requests module here

```
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/
```

But they only have data value as key,value there

```
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

So how could in convert the above curl post request to python requests module to make post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you linked says:

> There are many times that you want to send data that is not form-encoded. If you pass in a string instead of a dict, that data will be posted directly.

So just use

```
r = requests.post('http://sss.com', data = 'aq=%40syssource%3DProFind%20AND%20NOT%20%40title%3DCoveo%20AND%20NOT%20%40title%3Derror&searchHub=ProFind&xxx=yyy&xxx=yyy&xxx=yyy=10&xxx=yyy')
```